# Copy-Item vs XCopy

Tags: powershell

I was asked to benchmark using a powershell script to do some basic file copying as opposed to using XCopy in a batch file.  It seems to run in roughly about the same amount of time, but with Powershell the parent folder of the tree structure is not being created in the destination, whereas with XCopy the parent folder does get created.  For example, with

```
xcopy D:\Webs\First\*.* D:\Test\Sandbox\ /E
```

The "First" folder does get created with all its contents.  Whereas with

```
$SourceFolder = "D:\\Webs\\First\\"
$TargetFolder = "D:\\Test\\Sandbox\\"

Copy-Item $SourceFolder $TargetFolder -recurse
```

The folder named "First" does not get created and rather the contents are copied to the destination.  If I use "Webs" as the source folder, there are other folders at the same level as "First" that get copied as well and that is not desirable.

How do I get the Parent folder "First" to copy to the destination using the Copy-Item or some other powershell command without manually creating this folder within the script so I get the exact same results?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a quick way you can append the source parent folder before copy, e.g.

```
$TargetFolder = "D:\\Test\\Sandbox\\"+($SourceFolder | Split-Path -leaf)
```

you can also use the [Measure-Command Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176899.aspx) for timings